# How to install RPY2 on Heroku?

Tags: python, r, heroku, rpy2

I have a project that uses RPY2. 
However, when the requirements.txt file executes, Heroku throws:

```
Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH
```

I am using the https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/tree/heroku-16 R buildpack. It sets up an R buildpack and the init.r file is run. I have tried to use following config vars to solve the issue:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/app/vendor/R/lib64/R/modules:/app/vendor/R/lib64/R/lib:/app/vendor/gcc-4.3/lib64
```

and

```
PATH = /app/vendor/R/bin:/app/vendor/gcc-4.3/bin:/app/.heroku/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

What should I do to successfully run RPY2?

Comment: Like it says on the Github repo you shared: "NOTE: This version is DEPRECATED. Please use the heroku-16 branch." Try [this one](https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r/tree/heroku-16) instead.

Comment: @cosinepenguin the problem persists I am afraid.